# SpatialJoin_analysis with delimiter

Tags: arcpy

`SpatialJoin_analysis` is not working with delimiter semicolon (`;`).  It only worked with a comma delimiter (`,`)

```
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(Unique_Intersections,
                       Streets_Unsplit,
                       Signed_Intersections,
                       "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE",
                       "KEEP_ALL",
                       "IntersectionName \"IntersectionName\" true true false 150 Text 0 0 ,Join,\" , \",G:\\xStreetNew\\Test.gdb\\RoadCenterline_Unsplit,STREETNM,-1,-1",
                       "INTERSECT",
                       "1 Meters", "")
```

[image]

If I change the delimiter (`,`) (highlighted in yellow above) to (`;`), it won't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: That option is for `Field Mapping`. Please refer to document help at http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm

Comment: Semicolon works in the spatial join tool. Run the tool, open geoprocessing, results, right-click command, Copy as Python snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work using FieldMapping.

```
import arcgisscripting, sys
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

fieldmappings = gp.CreateObject("FieldMappings")
fieldmappings.AddTable(Streets_Unsplit_Intersections)
fieldmappings.AddTable(Streets_Unsplit)
fieldmap = fieldmappings.GetFieldMap(fieldmappings.FindFieldMapIndex("STREETNM"))
field = fieldmap.OutputField
field.Name = "IntersectionName"
field.AliasName = "IntersectionName"
fieldmap.OutputField = field
fieldmap.MergeRule = "join"
fieldmap.joinDelimiter = ';'
fieldmappings.ReplaceFieldMap(fieldmappings.FindFieldMapIndex("STREETNM"), fieldmap)

arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(Streets_Unsplit_Intersections,
                       Streets_Unsplit,
                       Streets_Intersections,
                       "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE",
                       "KEEP_ALL",
                       fieldmappings,
                       "INTERSECT",
                       "1 Meters", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try raw strings?  They allow you to do all sorts of characters without special formatting.

It's a must for filepaths or complex strings that would chew python up:
-instead of putting "yourstring" you put r'yourstring'

so r'S:yourfolder\otherfolders\example' is perfectly acceptable. It might save you from breaking up that string argument, and you can use double quotes in a r'' string or single quotes in an r"" raw string without having to denote special chars.  Just a wild guess.